# How to test function depending on other objects in jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I have a jasmine unit test for a backbone model called Event.

In this model I have a function:

```
getParticipants: function(){
  new Myappp.Collections.UsersCollection(
    this.get("participations").map(function(participation){
      return participation.get("user");
    });
  );
}
```

It has 4 dependencies:

- User model
- Users collection
- Participation model
- Participations collections

I want to test all models in isolation, as it is best practice, but I'm not sure how.

I'm using sinon.js for mocking and stubbing, but don't know how to use it correctly in this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `getParticipants` is doing a lot of things.. actually 3 things, so I rather will try to make it focus in one only thing: build the `Myappp.Collections.UsersCollection`. And move all the previous needed calculations to another methods.

And then you'll can focus in the very tricky one: **to mock the `new` call**.

I'd do it in 3 phases:

#### 1. Move the Users filter to another place

I suggest to move it to a method in the `Myapp.Collections.ParticipationsCollection`, then we can just call it from our `Event` instance like this:

```
Myapp.Models.Event = 
  Backbone.Model.extend({
    getParticipants: function(){
      var usersArray   = this.get("participations").getUsers();
      var participants = new Myapp.Collections.UsersCollection(usersArray);

      return participants;
    }
  });

Myapp.Collections.ParticipationsCollection = 
  Backbone.Collection.extend({
    getUsers: function(){
      var users = 
        this.map(function(participation){
          return participation.get("user");
        });

      return users;
    }
  });
```

This way we can easily *mocking* the `getUsers` method to test our target method.

#### 2. Wrapping, even more, the Users Array obtaining

I the code example above we still have a complicate chain methods call in the line `this.get("participations").getUsers()` we can move it to a custom method also easy to mock:

We finish with something like this:

```
Myapp.Models.Event = 
  Backbone.Model.extend({
    getParticipants: function(){
      var usersArray   = this.getUsersArray();
      var participants = new Myapp.Collections.UsersCollection( usersArray );

      return participants;
    },

    getUsersArray: function(){
      return this.get("participations").getUsers();
    }
  });
```

#### 3. Test the Collection initialization

Now we have to focus in mocking the Collection `Myapp.Collections.UsersCollection` and check that our method in initializing and entity of this Collection with the proper params.

The *proper params* are the result of the method `Event.getUsersArray()` and now we can easily mock it.

Sinon has an especial expectation to check if a method has been called with `new`..

My Jasmine/Sinon approach to this is not really accurate due I'm not testing that the method is returning the *new* Collection, I hope someone can come with a better implementation:

```
describe("Event", function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    testModel = new Myapp.Models.Event();
  });

  it("getParticipants returns proper Collection", function() {
    var usersCollectionSpy = sinon.spy( Myapp.Collections, "UsersCollection" );

    var getUsersArrayMock = sinon.stub(testModel, "getUsersArray");
    getUsersArrayMock.returns( "usersArray" );

    testModel.getParticipants();

    expect( usersCollectionSpy.calledWith( "usersArray" ) ).toBeTruthy();
    expect( usersCollectionSpy.calledWithNew() ).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/J5WTf/)